# how to set UILabel to specific number of characters

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have a which has width 240 and size of characters is 28, I want to display only 16 characters if string comes more than 16, after 16 characters it should show triple dots just like truncated. I have did following try but it did not work.

```
 if(place_title.length>=16){
            place_title.autoresizesSubviews=YES;

        }
        else{
            place_title.autoresizesSubviews=NO;
            place_title.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;

        }
```

It truncated words around 12 characters. I want to just show 16 character, not to compromise n size of label (to grow size of label) but will compromise on size of string(decrease the size of characters) in label. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you can't do something like

```
if (place_title.length > 16){
    place_title = [[place_title substringToIndex:15] stringByAppendingString:@"..."];
}
```

rather than trying to get UILabel to do this for you?